# Is distribution of uniform random variables $\leq$ standard normal variable at 0 and 1?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

$Let\ X_1,\ X_2,\ ...\ be\ independent\ r.v.s\ with\ X_n\ \sim Uniform(-n,\ 3n)\ where\ n\ =\ 1,\ 2,\ ... $

$$Let\ S_N\ =\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\ \begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\ \dfrac{X_n}{n}\ \end{align}\ for\ N = 1, 2, ..\infty\\ $$
$Let\ F_N\ be\ the\ distribution\ function\ of\ S_N\\ Also\ let\ \phi\ denote\ the\ distribution\ function\ of\ a\ standard\ normal\ random\ variable.$
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} F_N(0)\ \leq\ \phi\ (0)?\ \\ \lim_{N\to\infty} F_N(1)\ \leq \phi\ (1)?$$
$How\ to\ prove\ that\ the\ above\ conditions\ are\ true?$

Comment: Please comment before downvoting.

Comment: This is a valid question and a bit challenging too. I don't see the reason for downvote.

Comment: Is there a typo (e.g., should it be $\text{Uniform}(-3n, 3n)$)? As it stands, $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n/n$ is the mean of i.i.d. $X_n/n \sim \text{Uniform}(-1, 3)$ which converges to $1$ as $N \to \infty$ by the LLN. Multiplying this term by $\sqrt{N}$ yields $S_N$, which would blow up to infinity as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: No there is no typo in the question. Thanks for your comment. Could you please write it as answer a bit more elaborately?

Comment: Is my explanation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
    Y_n = \dfrac{X_n - n}{3n}
\end{equation}
And by a simple computation we can see,
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
    Y_n\ is\ i.i.d.\ \sim U(-\dfrac{2}{3},\ \dfrac{2}{3})
\end{equation}
Also from (1), we can write
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
    X_n = 3nY_n + n
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
        S_N = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\ \dfrac{X_n}{n}\\
            From\ (3)\ we\ can\ write,\\
            = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\ \dfrac{n + 3nY_n}{n}\\
            = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\ 1 + 3Y_n\\
            = 3\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\ Y_n\ +\ \sqrt{N}\\
\end{equation}
By Central Limit Theorem, the first term tends to a normal distribution and the whole R.H.S. tends to,
$As\ (N\ \rightarrow\ \infty)\\$
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
        S_N = 3\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\ Y_n\ +\ \sqrt{N}\ \longrightarrow\ \infty\\
\end{equation}
$\because\ S_N\ \rightarrow\ \infty$, it implies
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
        \lim_{N \to \infty}\ F_N(0) = 0\\
        \lim_{N \to \infty}\ F_N(1) = 0
\end{equation}

By definition we know, a standard normal random variable is a normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ = 0  and standard deviation $\sigma$ = 1 . It is denoted by the letter  Z. From Z-distribution table we know,
\begin{equation}\tag{7}
        P(Z\leqslant 0) = \phi(0) = 0.5\\
        P(Z\leqslant 1) = \phi(1) = 0.84134
\end{equation}
Hence by comparing (6) and (7) we see both conditions in the question are true.

Comment: Your work looks fine, although the question seems very weird. If the author intended for $F_N$ to converge to zero pointwise, it seems pointless to ask to compare the limit specifically to $\phi(0)$ and $\phi(1)$, rather than just stating that the limit is zero. This is why I think there is a typo in the question.